# How can I change a command line argument in Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to change the command line arguments in a Bash script? For example, a Bash script is invoked like this:

```
./foo arg1 arg2
```

Is there a way to change the value of `arg1` within the script? Something like:

```
$1="chintz"
```

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You have to reset all arguments. To change, e.g., argument `$3`:

```
set -- "${@:1:2}" "new_arg3" "${@:4}"
```

Basically you [set](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) *all* arguments to their current values, except for the one(s) that you want to change. `set --` is also specified [by POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set).

The [`"${@:1:2}"` notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is expanded to the two (hence the `2` in the notation) positional arguments, starting from offset `1` (i.e. `$1`). It is a shorthand for `"$1" "$2"` in this case, but it is much more useful when you want to replace, e.g., `"${17}"`.

Comment: so, in order to change $3, I must change $1 and $2 as well, is it? And change them to what? What does "reset" mean?

Comment: Thanks for the trick!  I had difficulty using this for filenames with embedded spaces.  For anyone else who may run into that problem, try putting `eval` at the front of the line per [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-preserving-whitespace-using-set-and-eval).

Comment: This is ok when you know the position of the parameter you want to change.

What if you actually don't know it and need to change it dynamically?

I tried with $ set -- "${:1:$pivot}" but it doesn't accept a variable there.

Comment: How can I do the same thing from inside a function? Your solution doesn't seem to work when invoked from inside a function.

Comment: You cannot change the positional parameters of a script from within a function - the function's own arguments hide them. You can, however, store them in an array and operate on that.

Comment: I needed some additional help to understand this answer, so I wrote [an explanatory and more-thorough answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76081159/4561887). Thanks for your work to get me started.

Answer (score 26):

Optimising for legibility and maintainability, you may be better off assigning `$1` and `$2` to more meaningful variables (I don't know, `input_filename = $1` and `output_filename = $2` or something) and then overwriting one of those variables (`input_filename = 'chintz'`), leaving the input to the script unchanged, in case it is needed elsewhere.

Comment: I wanted an approach where I could alter one of the input arguments itself. I needed to do that since I wanted to return a value from the script. The answer suggested by thkala worked well. Thanks for the response!!!

Comment: @Johnsyweb Agreed. For readability sake, yours is the better method.

Comment: "You are better off" always depends on the use case, which is not provided.

Comment: @Scott 7 years older and more experience than I was when I wrote this answer, I'm inclined to agree with you.

Comment: Example where this would not work (apart from using something like $FIRST_PARAMETER): having the use and meaning of the parameter depending on the actual value.

Comment: @Sriram I cannot imagine a situation where you cannot pass the value of a variable and then return that from a script. Do you mind clarifying in what scenario this answer would not work?

Answer (score 9):

I found [the answer by *thkala*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827690/how-can-i-change-a-command-line-argument-in-bash/4827707#4827707) very helpful, so I have used the idea and expanded on it slightly to enable me to add defaults for any argument which has not been defined. For example:

```
# Set defaults for the passed arguments (if any) if not defined.
#
arg1=${1:-"default-for-arg-1"}
arg2=${2:-"default-for-arg-2"}
set -- "${arg1}" "${arg2}"
unset arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 4):

### How to change command-line arguments `$1`, `$2`, etc. in Bash using `set --`

As an addition to the [main answer on Ask Ubuntu by @Radu Rădeanu here](https://askubuntu.com/a/441222/327339), and to the [main answer by @thkala on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827707/4561887), I'd like to add a really simple example to set multiple arguments at once like this:

```
# Set arguments `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` to these respective values
set -- "one" "two" "three"
echo "$1 $2 $3"
```

Output:

```
one two three
```

If you have additional arguments after the arguments you want to change, you can keep them by slicing them onto the end, like this:

```
set -- "one" "two" "three" "${@:4}"
```

I explain the `"${@:4}"` slicing syntax in my answer here: [Unix & Linux: Bash: slice of positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664956/114401). See that answer for much more detail on *bash array slicing*. Here is a small snippet from it:

> ```
> # Array slicing basic format 1: grab a certain length starting at a certain
> # index
> echo "${@:2:5}"
> #         │ │
> #         │ └────> slice length
> #         └──────> slice starting index
>
> # Array slicing basic format 2: grab all remaining array elements starting at a
> # certain index through to the end
> echo "${@:2}"
> #         │
> #         │
> #         └──────> slice starting index
> ```

So, in the [main answer by @thkala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827707/4561887), which contains this:

```
set -- "${@:1:2}" "new_arg3" "${@:4}"
```

...the explanation is that `"${@:1:2}"` grabs the first 2 arguments, `"new_arg3"` inserts that as a new argument 3, and `"${@:4}"` grabs all arguments from 4 to the end, thereby changing only argument 3 and keeping all other arguments as they were.

For help on the `set` built-in bash command, see `help set` or look online here: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin

`help set` shows the following for the `--` argument:

> ```
>   --  Assign any remaining arguments to the positional parameters.
>       If there are no remaining arguments, the positional parameters
>       are unset.
> ```

### See also

1. My shorter answer on Ask Ubuntu here: [How to change the value of an argument in a script?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464749/327339)