# git stash doesn't show with me after i stash save a untracked file

Tags: git

git stash doesn't show untracked files after I use `git stash save -u`:

```
D:\kzxd-usm\KzxdUsm>git status
Already up-to-date!
# On branch work
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       WebRoot/WEB-INF/jsp/usm/org/Copy of list.jsp
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I want list the untracked file after it's stashed with `git stash save -u`:

```
D:\kzxd-usm\KzxdUsm>git stash list --stat
stash@{0}: On work: hide copy of list.jsp
```

It has only a little comment text and does not have stashed file information.

Comment: This question is hard to understand...

Comment: lyrl obviously doesn't write english very well.  I think it is quite cruel to downvote them because of that.  Instead it would have been nicer to try and help extract what they are trying to say.  I could easily work out that they are saying "'git stash show' doesn't show untracked files".  Its a valid question. I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In git, is there a way to show untracked stashed files without applying the stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681529/in-git-is-there-a-way-to-show-untracked-stashed-files-without-applying-the-stas)

Answer (score 6):

use `git show stash@{0}^3` to show all the untracked files stashed.

Comment: A little explanation of why this works would be nice.

Comment: [Here](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190904072926.GA18470@sigill.intra.peff.net/) it's a bit more explained.
Hope one day someone will improve it. Git GUIs like GitExtension or Visual studio doesn't have problem with showing added files to stash.

Comment: This no longer works with newer versions of git.

Answer (score 2):

In my 1.7.8.2, stash@{0}^3 does not work to show untracked files. However, I have found that the following does list them in the the second log entry:

git log -2 --name-only stash@{0}

You can use -p instead of --name-only if you want to see the file details.

Answer (score 1):

If you stash with `git stash save -u` and then do `git stash show`, untracked files will not be shown -- the listing will contain changes to tracked files only.

It makes sense when you want to share your stashed changes with someone: The diff you get from `git stash show` won't contain any extra garbage (the untracked stuff from your working copy) but only the relevant changes to tracked files.

Once you restore your stashed changes with `git pop`, the untracked files will be restored as well.

Comment: I dont' think this behaviour makes sense at all.  Stashes are private (can you share them???).  That issue just freaked me out as I thought I'd somehow lost all the work I had done last week ("damm I must have rebased them out of existence").  Ideally I would interim commit work, though sometimes I just reach for the 'ole `stash` command without thinking.

Comment: Afaik, they're completely private/local. By sharing I meant sharing the plain diff/patch -- via copying, emailing or by other means.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't make sense. On git [mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/20170317141417.g2oenl67k74nlqrq@sigill.intra.peff.net/) I found: "I don't think there is a good reason. The "untracked" option was added to git-stash much later, and nobody considered how it interacted with "stash show"."

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I found is at [In git, is there a way to show untracked stashed files without applying the stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681529/in-git-is-there-a-way-to-show-untracked-stashed-files-without-applying-the-stas/23712152#23712152) and this answer in particular - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23712152/1019307.

```
git rev-list -g stash | git rev-list --stdin --max-parents=0 | xargs git show --stat
```

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` will only stash changes in files that git knows about: it won't stash changes in untracked files.

You can tell git about the file using `git add`, then stash the changes using `git stash`:

```
git add Copy\ of\ list.jsp
git stash
```

Comment: True but the `-u/--include-untracked` will add them.  Often you want to stash untracked files.  The question was asking how to show untracked stashed files.  That issue just freaked me out as I thought I'd somehow lost all the work I had done last week ("damm I must have rebased them out of existence").  I don't like this behaviour of not showing untracked stashed files.