# Reference git stash by number without stash@{i}

Tags: git, bash-completion

I'm using git stashes extensively. Sometimes it becomes annoying to type out `stash@{3}` when, at first glance, a simple `3` should suffice. Is it possible to use the shorter reference somehow?

I know a solution with shell aliases. Making an alias like

```
sshow = "!f { git stash show @{$@}; }; f"
```

allows using `git sshow 1`. It even allows passing additional arguments to `git stash show` if `$@` is expanded properly.

However, in this case git autocomplete does not work: when `git stash show stash@{0} --<Tab><Tab>` is typed it should show all `git diff` options, but here it knows nothing about the underlying command.

Are there other ways of making such alias which preserve original `git diff` completion context?

Comment: Try to do `git stash --<Tab><Tab>` and make a right conclusion after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is built-in to Git as of v2.11. You can refer to any stash by index only. For example, to apply the stash at index 2 you can type

```
git stash apply 2
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm using git 2.7.4 and it is still not available there. It is awesome that this feature has native support now, I should update my client.

Comment: FYI, it was specifically added in Git 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), `git stash` is rewritten in C.

See [commit 7906af0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7906af0cb84c8e65656347909abd4e22b04d1c1e), [commit 90a4627](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90a462725ef3932a2408e78a47e3dfc1b8d445cf), [commit 8d8e9c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d8e9c2a94c4cb60a0db2a496fd1f28fc6ec79f8) (25 Feb 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 40af146](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40af14683432285b94407e8488eab6942d0779dc), [commit 48ee24a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48ee24ab72b4ffd40789a99281066d79c2c5a720), [commit ef0f0b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef0f0b4509ae8bd6736dacf740d9e1bc1281f7bd), [commit 64fe9c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64fe9c26a479082eb80a9d68e8b3b7686e8c2b26), [commit 1ac528c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac528c0b0c3f3e8a5faa75ea25f422fcbc2ba39), [commit d553f53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d553f538b8a788a4a285af2000edf3285694182e), [commit d4788af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4788af875cc5c027c42b85435b022edb00b9fda), [commit 41e0dd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/41e0dd55c4300dc83ea2883bf04bfb234c071f98), [commit dc7bd38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc7bd382b1063303f4f45d243bff371899285acb), [commit 130f269](https://github.com/git/git/commit/130f2697daf60f09a15884a4510b4fa0230eee98), [commit bef55dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bef55dcf27060e57512ad99318a0d7de5b4ed6bb), [commit dac566c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dac566c507baeb4921e1b8ad8d39e8145ca80c12), [commit ab8ad46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab8ad46ec70afbc0468c2c2cff817dc54c66ca79) (25 Feb 2019) by [Paul-Sebastian Ungureanu (`weekly-digest[bot]`)](https://github.com/weekly-digest[bot]).
See [commit c4de61d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4de61d7a95ebb7197191bc51475d19068b6d526), [commit 577c199](https://github.com/git/git/commit/577c1995e8c8cb414a6beb430f220e1ded216a64), [commit 4e2dd39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e2dd393031bba5abf32f1df6aff107903cabcfd), [commit 8a0fc8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0fc8d19dff0c0ed09ce6656e353daf06c21892) (25 Feb 2019) by [Joel Teichroeb (`klusark`)](https://github.com/klusark).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e36adf7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e36adf712251a19bd2ada0016764d340dfcf2ba0), 22 Apr 2019)</sup>

---

And... "`git stash show 23`" **used to work, but no more after getting rewritten in C**; this regression has been corrected in Git 2.23 (Q3 2019).

See [commit 63b50c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63b50c8ffe7133d2ec7d243dd9240c14ddfe8a26) (15 Jun 2019) by [Thomas Gummerer (`tgummerer`)](https://github.com/tgummerer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 99af5be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99af5bedbda020571995f207e30a617310472a04), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### stash: fix show referencing stash index
>
> In the conversion of '`stash show`' to C in [dc7bd38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc7bd382b1063303f4f45d243bff371899285acb) ("`stash`: convert
>   show to builtin", 2019-02-25, Git v2.22.0-rc0), '`git stash show <n>`', where `n` is the
>   index of a stash got broken, if `n` is not a file or a valid revision by
>   itself.
>
> '`stash show`' accepts any flag '`git diff`' accepts for changing the output format.
>   Internally we use '`setup_revisions()`' to parse these command line flags.
>   Currently we pass the whole `argv` through to '`setup_revisions()`', which includes the stash index.
>
> As the stash index is not a valid revision or a file in the working tree in most cases however, this '`setup_revisions()`' call (and thus the whole command) ends up failing if we use this form of '`git stash show`'.
>
> Instead of passing the whole `argv` to '`setup_revisions()`', only pass
>   the flags (and the command name) through, while excluding the stash
>   reference.
>   The stash reference is parsed (and validated) in '`get_stash_info()`' already.
>
> This separate parsing also means that we currently do produce the
>   correct output if the command succeeds.