# Alias for 'git stash drop' in zsh

Tags: linux, git, terminal, alias, zsh

I want to make an `alias` to drop a git stash in zsh shell. The stash no. which I want to drop should be passed as an argument to my function call.

I have tried below but it is failing -

```
function gd() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        git stash drop "$1"
    else
        echo 'Enter stash no to drop'
    fi
}
```

It gives me below error -

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Seems I am not passing the argument correctly and it is being treated as a string.

How can I make this work?

Comment: How did you actually call `gd`?

Answer (score 1):

@ShantanuTomar : You don't define any alias, which is not a bad thing in the first place, because a function is more flexible anyway, but if you really want to have an `alias`,  the command to define it would be

```
 alias gd='git stash drop'
```

Aside from this, your function definition is fine, though you don't need to quote your variables. It doesn't harm doing so, though.

The error message says that the stash you provided, does not exist. Use

```
git stash list
```

to get a list of the available stashes.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
git stash drop $1
```

But, as commented, there won't be any kind of conversion done by zsh alone.

So, make sure to use a recent enough Git:

- `git stash` using numbers (then interpreted as `stash@{n}`) is only supported [since Git 2.11 (Q4 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543440/6309)
- there was a bug associated with `git stash` and its index, [fixed in Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57029901/6309)

Comment: `$1` is a string either way. Quoting is necessary if the branch name contains characters that the shell might process before `git` ever sees it; it doesn't do any kind of type conversion.

Comment: @chepner: Not in this case, because we have Zsh. Even if $1 would contain wildcards, they would not be evaluated if unquoted.

Comment: That depends on your shell settings. Either way, though, not quoting doesn't make the shell treat it as an integer, because even `zsh` doesn't have an integer data type: it's all strings.