# How to view the untracked files in a JGit RevCommit?

Tags: egit, jgit

I'm working on a Git Client based on JGit and I'm trying to implement stash support. To display the files in the stash, I used the `git.diff ()` command, but the untracked files are not shown. For the other file types it works great. How can I view untracked files as well?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681856/1288460