# how to tell a bash script to parse a single command-line argument that contains spaces?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that accepts multiple command line arguments ($1, $2, ... etc). The program that's launching the script is, for reasons I won't get into here, passing the command line arguments as one string which the bash script interprets as $1. This one string contains spaces between the desired arguments, but bash is still interpreting it as a solitary command line argument. Is there a way to tell bash to parse it's command line argument using a space as delimiter?

For example, if argstring = `50 graphite downtick` I want bash to see `$1=50` `$2=graphite` `$3=downtick`, instead of `$1=50 graphite downtick`

Comment: Don't quote the expansion, and it will get word split (but it will split on every space, which might not be what you want either. And watch out for globs.)

Comment: @rici I don't understand what you mean by "don't quote the expansion."

Comment: When you use $1. Presumably you use it somewhere. If you want to split it into positional parameters, you could use `set -- $1`. If you want to pass it to a different command as three words: `other_cmd $1`. As long as you don't ​quote the expansion (`"$1"`), it will get split. +But it's a suboptimal way to pass multiple arguments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line at the top of your program:

```
set -- $1
```

More info about `set` in [the bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) and another example of its usage in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827690/change-a-command-line-argument-in-bash). Basically, it can be used to replace the arguments being passed into your script.