# bad substitution when creating nested array variables in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I don't know what I am doing and could use some assistance with my script.

`$ ./mysql.sh LOCALIP 'SELECT LOCALIP FROM Host'`

mysql.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source $PWD/data/login

mapfile -t "$1" < <(mysql -N ""$DB"" -h""$HOST"" -u""$USER"" -p""$PASS"" -se "$2")

echo ${$1[0]}
echo ${$1[1]}
echo ${$1[2]}
echo ${$1[3]}

fi
```

Output

```
[シ]owner@gwpi ~/scriptdir $./mysql.sh LOCALIP 'SELECT LOCALIP FROM Host'
./mysql.sh: line 10: ${$1[0]}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Might have found an answer to my question elsewhere and here it is:
```eval "echo \${$1[0]}"```

Comment: Don't double the double-quotes. In `""$DB""`, each pair of double-quotes creates a zero-length quoted section, which has no effect at all on the argument(s) passed to the `mysql` command (unless `$DB` evaluates to the null string, in which case they prevent it from just vanishing from the argument list). Since `$DB` isn't in double-quotes, it's subject to all word-splitting and wildcard expansion, neither of which you want. Also, you can't nest variable expansions like `${$1[0]}` (what are you trying to do there?). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) would've spotted these; use it!

Comment: Also, `$HOST` and `$USER` (and many other all-caps variable names) have special meanings in the shell; unless you specifically want those special meanings, it's safer to user lower- or mixed-case variable names for a script's internal variables.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I am creating for fun a self hosted system monitoring service. My various boxes would run a script that uploads some basic information like VPN status, externalip about themselves to my mysql server and that information would be displayed about each upon logging into any of them in a motd.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the varible `$1` with `var` here.It works.

```
$ mapfile -t var < <(mysql -N ""$DB"" -h""$HOST"" -u""$USER"" -p""$PASS"" -se "$2")
$ echo" ${var[@]}"
```

Original script has two problems.

- You cannot change `$1` arg in this way.Right style refers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827690/how-to-change-a-command-line-argument-in-bash)
- should be better using more meaningful variables than `$1`

Comment: might need some explanations about the changes.

Comment: I cannot get the code to format correctly to post all of it but you can run a script like `./script.sh test` that contains `echo $1`, the result is test.

Comment: Here is an example of passing the $1 (and $2, $3) arguments along in shell scripts as modifiers/switches. I don't know the proper terminology for this.

https://pastebin.com/vuT32H5Y